# How to correctly write a UI test for a Swift UI Toggle

Tags: ios, swiftui, xctest

Does anyone know how to correctly write a UI test for a Toggle? Even in a brand new project with just a Toggle and nothing else in the entire UI I keep getting this sort of error:

```
Failed to get matching snapshot: Multiple matching elements found for <XCUIElementQuery: 0x60000108c410>.
Sparse tree of matches:
→Application, pid: 26580, label: 'TestToggle'
 ↳Window (Main)
  ↳Other
   ↳Other
    ↳Other
     ↳Other
      ↳Switch, label: 'Test switch', value: 1
       ↳Switch, label: 'Test switch', value: 1
```

UI looks like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
  @State private var toggleValue = true
  var body: some View {
    Toggle("Test switch", isOn: $toggleValue)
      .padding()
  }
}
```

Test looks like this (either of those lines gives me this same error):

```
     func testExample() throws {
        let app = XCUIApplication()
        app.launch()
        
        XCTAssertTrue(app.switches["Test switch"].value as? String == "1")
//        XCTAssertTrue(app.switches["Test switch"].isEnabled)
    }
```

Surely I’m doing something wrong. How can there be two switches showing up if there’s only one? None of the online articles seem to mention anything about this that I’ve seen. Any help appreciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I got a few responses in some slack channels and it turns out that for some reason using a Toggle I can't rely on the default label for testing (unlike Text and Button) and need to create a custom accessibility identifier.

So just add something like this:

```
    Toggle("Test switch", isOn: $toggleValue)
        .padding()
        .accessibilityIdentifier("testSwitch")
```

and then test like this works:

```
func testExample() throws {
    let app = XCUIApplication()
    app.launch()
    XCTAssertTrue(app.switches["testSwitch"].isEnabled)
    XCTAssertTrue(app.switches["testSwitch"].value as? String == "1")
}
```

Comment: I am not sure if your test asserts what you want to test. `isEnabled` returns "whether or not the element is enabled for user interaction."

If a user can interact with it it, `isEnabled ` returns `true`, even if the Toggle is off.

Comment: Yes you are correct I was trying to test that it was turned on. Thanks :) However that was not the issue I was facing. The issue was with the accessibilityIdentifier. I've updated the answer to include both.

Comment: It's weird you can't rely on the provided label.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you are getting the error you are getting, but you could try adding a `accessibilityIdentifier` to the Toggle and find it that way.

For example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
  @State private var toggleValue = true
  var body: some View {
    Toggle("Test switch", isOn: $toggleValue)
      .padding()
      .accessibilityIdentifier("testSwitch")
  }
}
```

And in your test, you can then find the element with:

```
func testExample() throws {
        let app = XCUIApplication()
        app.launch()
        
        XCTAssertTrue(app.switches["testSwitch"].value as? String == "1")
    }
```

By the way, if you want to test whether the Toggle is on or off, you should **not** use `isEnabled`. This will check "whether or not the element is enabled for user interaction."

You should use

```
app.switches["testSwitch"].value as? String == "1" // on
```

or

```
app.switches["testSwitch"].value as? String == "0" // off
```

depending on what you want to test.

Comment: I already put an answer for using `accessibilityIdentifier` 3.5 months ago as you can see above. Not sure why you are posting the same answer again.

Comment: @MichaelVescovo Your answer used `isEnabled` and I was not sure if that was the thing you tried to test. I thought you wanted to test whether the switch was on or off.

Comment: The reason it wasn't working is because I didn't add an `accessibilityIdentifier`. This was answered previously and then again in your answer. If your answer didn't require using an 'accessibilityIdentifier' then sure it would be helpful but that's not that case.

Comment: @MichaelVescovo I understand, I probably should have left out the accessibilityIdentifier part. To be honest, I did not notice that your answer already included that part. The thing I was trying to point out is that you use `.isEnabled` in your test. The `.isEnabled` part will always return true unless you specified the `.disabled(true)`. I was not sure if you were aware of this, since you might be testing the wrong thing.

Comment: I got a chance to test this. Yes you are correct; I want to test both that it's enabled and turned on. Thanks for the tip! The issue I was trying to solve with my question was the issue with the accessibilityIdentifier but you found a bug in my test. Thanks :) I've updated the answer to include both.