# SwiftUI toggle not being toggled in UI test

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, xcode-ui-testing

I can't get UI tests to toggle a Toggle in a SwiftUI Form. It seems that `app.switches[*name*].tap()` does nothing. Does anyone else have experienced this? Ideas?

The code below is a demonstration of the issue. It's a simple form with four toggles that generates a int value based on the toggles positions.

I have the following SwiftUI view:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var sw1: Bool = false
    @State var sw2: Bool = false
    @State var sw3: Bool = false
    @State var sw4: Bool = false
    
    
    var valueString: String {
        var ret: Int = 0
        if sw1 {
            ret = ret + 1
        }
        if sw2 {
            ret = ret + 2
        }
        if sw3 {
            ret = ret + 4
        }
        if sw4 {
            ret = ret + 8
        }
        return String(ret)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            Form {
                Section("Binary switches"){
                    Toggle("1", isOn: $sw1)
                        .accessibilityIdentifier("sw1")
                    Toggle("2", isOn: $sw2)
                        .accessibilityIdentifier("sw2")
                    Toggle("4", isOn: $sw3)
                        .accessibilityIdentifier("sw3")
                    Toggle("8", isOn: $sw4)
                        .accessibilityIdentifier("sw4")
                }
                Section("Value") {
                    Text(valueString)
                        .accessibilityIdentifier("value")
                        .accessibilityValue(valueString)
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Test Form")
        }
    }
}
```

And the following UI tests Code:

```
func testRandomSwitches() throws {
    let app = XCUIApplication()
    app.launch()
    
    // Get the binary switches
    let sw1 = app.switches["sw1"]
    let sw2 = app.switches["sw2"]
    let sw3 = app.switches["sw3"]
    let sw4 = app.switches["sw4"]
    
    // randomly switch on some of the switches
    let randomOnes = [sw1, sw2, sw3, sw4].map { _ in Bool.random() }
    if randomOnes[0] { sw1.tap() }
    if randomOnes[1] { sw2.tap() }
    if randomOnes[2] { sw3.tap() }
    if randomOnes[3] { sw4.tap() }
    
    // calculate the expected value
    let expectedValue = randomOnes.enumerated()
        .filter { $0.element }
        .map { 1 << $0.offset }
        .reduce(0, +)
    
    // get the value text and assert that it matches the expected value
    let value = app.staticTexts["value"].value as? String ?? ""
    XCTAssertEqual(value, String(expectedValue))
}
```

When I run this test, the switches never get toggled, and the value string always reads "0". The UITest code fails on `XCTAssertEqual(value, String(expectedValue))`. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

If I try to record the toggle tap I always get the error "Timestamped Event Matching Error: Failed to find matching element".

Can anyone help me figure out why the switches aren't getting toggled in my UI tests?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to correctly write a UI test for a Swift UI Toggle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71096678/how-to-correctly-write-a-ui-test-for-a-swift-ui-toggle)

Comment: Unfortunately not. The answers suggest adding a `.accessibilityIdentifier()` to the toggle, witch I already have.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Figured it out. It seems that I need to access the first switch in the switch. Really weird. But I gess UI testing is weird. It would be much appreciated if anyone got a less hacky solution.

Non working code:

```
sw1.tap()
```

Working code:

```
sw1.switches.firstMatch.tap()
```

Comment: Wow this did it for me too.. thank you! Would have never figured that out!

Comment: This behavior just started with Xcode 14.3. It may always have been intentional for Apple and the glitch just got fixed but who knows. Thank you!!!

Comment: Still persists in Xcode 15.

Comment: Has anyone seen anything like this in UIKit as well?

Comment: I'm wondering about the switches (aka toggle buttons) the docs for firstMatch (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuielementtypequeryprovider/2902250-firstmatch )

My issue now that I can toggle it - is to consistently & reliably find the toggle in a known state.

Answer (score 0):

If, for some reason, anyone is trying to do this through Appium/WebdriverIO, I used this post as a jumping off point and here was the soln I came up with.

```
  this.confirmPickupSwitchParent = "~confirmPickupSwitch";
  this.childSwitches = "-ios class chain:**/XCUIElementTypeSwitch";

  async swipeToConfirmPickup() {
    const confirmPickupSwitchSelector = await this.driver.$(
      this.confirmPickupSwitchParent
    );

    const insideSwitchSelector = await confirmPickupSwitchSelector.$(
      this.childSwitches
    );
    await insideSwitchSelector.click();
  }
```

Basically find the parent Toggle/Switch using the accessibilityID and then search for the embedded child Toggle/Switch using the iOS class chain.